# WebMatrix 2 Beta is not installing when we have MVC 4 installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webmatrix

I am not able to install web matrix 2 beta. I have MVC 4 installed. The screen says already installed but I have not found web matrix anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531566 & http://forums.asp.net/t/1661809.aspx